# what is the "f" mean in angular promise?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

Recently I have been learning in Angular to develop a new project.
When I use a `$q` or `$resource` to realize a ajax request

Here is the response when there is some data:

```
[{"number":"132412341234","type":"5","createTime":1388369479626,"updateTime":1388369479626,"kind":"devices#get","id":"52c0d6470cf2393bb3df6371"}]
```

Here is the response with no-data response:

```
[{"request":"persons/529c6a970cf2ce4b156d0f3e/devices","status":404,"error":"can't find persons records"}]
```

However,when I go back to my controller to get these data with promise:

```
var devices=DeviceResource.query({personId:1234});
```

response devices became:

```
[$promise: Object, $resolved: false]
    0: f
        $$hashKey: "00M"
        error: "can't find persons records"
        request:"persons/529c6a970cf2ce4b156d0f3e/devices"
        status: 404
        __proto__: f
    $promise: Object
    $resolved: true
    length: 1
    __proto__: Array[0]
```

the array[0]'s **proto** is "f"

what is the "f" mean? Where can I get these document?

It seems in angular `$q` document just some promise content.

Can anybody help me?
Thx a lot...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would assume you're using a minified version. Try using the production version instead to get a better trace, e.g.:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.js"></script>
```

Comment: I am guessing you meant to link to the *not* minified version? https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.js

Comment: Thx for your advice,but I still can't get anything I want after I switch a production version. How can I trace a __proto__ in chrome debug?

Comment: When I trace it in Scope Variables,here is some variables I can see:  [code](devices: Array[0]
$promise: Object
catch: function (callback) {
finally: function (callback) {
then: function (callback, errback, progressback) {
__proto__: Object
$resolved: false
length: 0
__proto__: Array[0])

Comment: my understanding is that $resource overwrites the fields of the promise with what is returned, and the promise is moved into $promise. So the prototype would presumably refer to what your query is returning. If you want to look at the promise, maybe you should use console.log() or something in your code right after you issue the request.

Comment: perhaps you could come up with a plunkr? looks like it's not resolving.

Comment: I just change my resource into a unminified version: here comes the console.log result:    [$promise: Object, $resolved: false]
0: Resource
$$hashKey: "00M"
error: "can't find persons records"
request: "persons/529c6a970cf2ce4b156d0f3e/devices"
status: 404
__proto__: Resource
$promise: Object
$resolved: true
length: 1
__proto__: Array[0]    It seems it's rewrite by ngResource!: )Thx a lot ~!